# After Downloading and Installing Tor My E-Mail Program is Drastically Slow

Tags: security, email

After Downloading and Installing Tor My E-Mail Program is Drastically Slow ... I am using Windows - 7 and Outlook 2013. Earthlink.net is my e-mail server.

Prior to downloading and installing TOR, my e-mail was working fine. Now when I send an e-mail, it sits there waiting, waiting and waiting for about 2 minutes before sending. Anyone know what is going on?

Does TOR install a program that effects Outlook 2013 e-mail program even when the TOR browser is not in use?

Answer (score 1):

2 minutes are 120 seconds - a very wide-defined connection timeout for network connections. No, it is not affecting any other software. If you've set your DNS to local Tor DNS listener, then it may wait for non-running Tor to resolve your DNS query(for your email server hostname), then retry the second DNS server. Or - if you've set Tor as a system-wide proxy and it's running - try to use services like WhatIsMyIP to check your IP address of the exit node you're using: maybe you need to set up a filter for exit nodes? It's because if not set explicitly, *any* reachable exit can be used, even the slowest one.